# Are 500 Euro notes accepted by banks in Spain?

Tags: money, spain, exchange

I am going to Spain and have some €500 notes. I have been advised that they are not accepted.

Will the **banks** accept them and change them?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46106/discussion-on-question-by-joan-are-500-euro-notes-accepted-in-spain).

Comment: I think it depends on a place mostly. Small shops and restaurants probably won't accept it, meanwhile huge stores and hotels (I rented apartments at Lugaris) take 500 euros without any problems.

Answer (score 40):

**Stores**

They are practically very rarely accepted. Not sure about how legal that is, but some stores even explicitly put signs they don't accept 500 EUR bills.

e.g. like this one (although this one is not from Spain):

[image]

**Banks**

For banks - I would be surprised if private banks where you don't have account, would go for breaking 500 into five 100s for you.
Probably only the national bank would do that - not sure how that works in Spain and how available are they.

Comment: My local supermarket has stickers not accepting €100 and €200, they do not even mention €500 as nobody here has those.

Comment: This is the right answer. Most stores will have some sign stating which notes they will refuse. Usually 200 and 500, sometimes even 100.

Comment: That point had already been made and the answer hardly seems to address the question, which is about banks.

Comment: *"Not sure about how legal this is"* - Where I live there is [a legal distinction](http://www.royalmint.com/aboutus/policies-and-guidelines/legal-tender-guidelines) between settlement of a debt and making an offer to purchase. Which means a retailer can make their own rules about what banknotes and coins they accept.

Comment: @Relaxed Good point, added a section on Banks.

Comment: The banks comment may be pretty false: every retail bank I ever walked into in Austria (which is also part of the Euro Zone) has an (explicit or implicit) cash counter where they *will* change your note into smaller notes. *However* they probably will charge an arm and a leg if you do not have an account there. Grzegorz, where are you from? Maybe we need a separate question to settle that :-)

Comment: @relaxed. True point. The question is a bit vague, I understood that the OP was asking if they could use the notes and the bank question was an afterthough. On second read I see your point.

Comment: I can say for personal experience that the bank will want to charge you if you are not a customer.

Comment: And then you have Switzerland when you whip out 1000CHF bill to pay for a bread + 2 buns and the baker won't even blink when counting your change.

Comment: @Willeke A supermarket won't accept €100? That's just crazy. What if you are spending €80-90 on food? Where is this? I never had any issues with $100 bills in the US.

Comment: @TheMathemagician I think `supermarket` has different meaning in Europe than US.  In the US what we call Supermarket (Jewel Osco or Safeway or whatnot) would always accept it (as a major corporation), but if you went into a corner store or a smaller grocer, many of those (at least where I live) will have signs "Do not accept notes over $20" presumably due to combination of avoiding fraud and avoiding keeping that much in change.

Comment: @TheMathemagician The actual text is 'we do not have change for €100 and €200, so if your shopping gets over €50, they should accept €100, and the same with €150 for a €200 notes, but I do not recall ever having seen notes over €50 been used by other customers. And while officially the sign makes they should accept the bigger notes, you can almost be certain that the big notes will not be handled at the normal till, you will be invited to pay at the 'service' till or will be invited to join them in the office where they will test the note.

Comment: Personal experience: I walked into a German bank where I have never been before and exchanged a 500 EUR note for 10 notes of size 50 EUR. I was not charged anything.

Answer (score 34):

500€ banknotes are perfectly legal in EU, and as such they are accepted all over the EU.

They are however been used a lot for criminal activities, so it's been decided that they will be faded out before the end of 2018; they were used a lot in Spain, especially, and on the opposite they now quite disappeared.

But this has nothing to do with you using them: as I said, they are perfectly legal. The real problem here is...where can you use them? Maybe you can go to a Valentino's store and pay a dress with 500 euro notes, but if you plan to go to e.g. the grocery...it's not that they will not accept them, it's just that they will not be able to give you the change. If you are willing to pay 500 euros for six eggs and a kilos of tomatoes...why not? ;-)

About the banks: as long as notes/coins are legal, they can be changed without worries. (even when they are not legal anymore, in many cases, but this is a totally different story)

Comment: Actually, they are not really "well accepted", precisely because most stores don't *(want to) have enough cash on hand to give change on a €500 note.

Comment: Any medium-sized or larger store will have €500 in change on hand; even many smaller ones will have it later in the day.

Comment: The problem with translating directly an Italian way of saying....I'll edit

Comment: @phoog Not really. Larger stores will certainly move much more than this in a day but make an effort not to keep that much cash in any individual check-out. Smaller shops might but even then, it would be hit and miss depending on how late you come, how much business they had in a given day and whether it's mostly cash-based or not.

Comment: @phoog any medium-sized store will move money to the bank many times a day to avoid becoming a target for armed robberies. And if they don't need to do this because they don't reach that business level, then they would hand a single customer 90% of their money for a single change to a 500 euro note, and proceed to refuse every other customer all day long because they can't do any change any more.

Comment: @Relaxed, motoDrizzt, well that was not my experience working retail, but that was over 25 years ago and not in Europe, so maybe not relevant.

Comment: @phoog Interestingly Europe (or even the eurozone) is very diverse in this respect. I do know some high-end shops in cash-friendly countries like Switzerland that are happy to accommodate very large cash payments, if necessary by asking the customers to go to a separate room. On the other hand, I know small businesses in France which wouldn't necessarily have that much cash, supermarkets with a pneumatic system to move the cash from the checkout to a safe as frequently as possible and countries where most transactions would be card-based.

Comment: @idmean: thx :-)

Comment: +1 to Relaxed. Plenty of places do not accept notes of 200€ or even 100£. For big places and purchases (home appliances, cars, etc) they will be flexible though.

Comment: @durum there is no £100 note

Comment: a few years ago in a quite big supermarket in downtown Scheveningen (NL)  they didn't want to accept my €200, for paying around €50 worth of goods. They had to call the manager, who after a short talk reluctantly agreed to take it.

Comment: @ASimmons there are no English £100 notes but there are £100 notes issued in Scotland, Northern Ireland and Jersey.

Comment: @SztupY which supports my (heretofore implicit) point: the reluctance to take these notes is very tenuously related to the ability to make change, if at all.  Of course a big supermarket can produce €150 in change.  It seems far more to do with avoidance of counterfeit notes or other fraud.

Comment: You might always end up with a supermarket clerk that simply has never seen a 500 Euro bill and thinks it's fake in general, because they didn't know it exists. That has happened to me in Germany with 10 Euro coins. Those are ment as collectibles, but they are also valid currency. But your average discount supermarket cashier has never heard of that and will call the manager.

Comment: @simbabque Just note that these non-standard euro coins are only valid currency in the country of issue. I can understand why people don't know they exist (and there are dozens of different ones). But a cashier not knowing about 500€ bills? That would raise my eyebrows...

Comment: I rolled back to an earlier version because the text was edited beyond what I think is acceptable.

Comment: The text was edited in a way I think should be encouraged. In my opinion, the answer was strictly better before the rollback and I propose it be undone.

Comment: @MarcksThomas Stack Exchange, as long as it accept users from all around the world, will be used by people from all around the world with different grades of English. While the occasional grammar errors fixing is a good thing to do (and something I often ask others to do on my posts), it's really annoying having peoples going around rewriting and rewording entire posts just because they feel they are better writers.

Comment: In the Netherlands they are not accepted almost anywhere. Even in large shops. Even if you try to spend 100+ euros. So there is an currency exchange office that breaks 500s for you for merely 1%. Yes, you have to pay 5e to break 500e, this is outrageous but basically there are no other options. Banks also will not break them. So saying that they are accepted all over EU is a stretch.

Comment: ECB may stop issuing new 500E banknotes, but I think this does not mean that existing 500E banknotes will become invalid. Simply they will become rare like 1000$. I think even 10,000$ exist on banknotes now but is hard to find such. Of course, nobody will accept them in a shop except if cashier is ex-bank officer and can recognize original banknote.

Comment: **tl;dr** They are not accepted everywhere. If anyone refuses to accept a bank note which is _too big_ (like €500) just go to any bank and exchange  it for smaller notes ... probably including a small fee.

Comment: @motoDrizzt: I'm sorry you felt annoyed by the revision, but everyone's contributions are subject to edits. That's the Stack Exchange format: a collaborative effort into building a high quality collection of questions and answers. We even expect edits to be substantial, as long as the original meaning is preserved. If you're uncomfortable with your posts being rewritten in this fashion, then this format may not be for you. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing.

Comment: @MarcksThomas While the edit did fix grammar, it also slightly changed the intent of the post (removing some humour and removing an extra point about banks). It would have been a fine edit if it was related to the grammar only. Changing the intent is not the SE-way.

Comment: @Relaxed In Spain it is currently illegal to pay business transactions of more than 2500 euros in cash. See http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/_componentes_/_Le_interesa_conocer/_Relacionados_/Nota_informativa.shtml

Comment: @DanFox OK, but why ping me, exactly?

Answer (score 24):

Spanish Here. They are rarely accepted because of security concerns, and usually (in small stores) that extends to 100 euro and 200 euro notes also.

If you need to use them, you can always ask for change in any bank.

Comment: Wait, they won't take my 100€ bill even if I make 100€ worth of purchases?

Comment: No, since the bill might be fake. That's the risk of high denomination notes - cashiers rarely handle genuine examples and can be easily tricked, plus criminals can spend moderate amounts (e.g. > 10€) per note making a high-quality forgery and still profit.

Comment: 200€ is totally not accepted where I live (Austria, also seen in Germany) too. The info for the €100 Notes is quite surprising - never seen anyone in any store that wouldn't accept it (*given* that you were paying an amount near on in excess of 100 € )

Comment: Here from Barcelona. If you purchase items for a value in the same order as the bank note, usually the only thing will be that they will check the note in a device to detect counterfeit. Anyway, you should avoid trying to pay a small purchase with a big note. Even trying to pay a 95 cent bar of bread with a 50E note won't make the baker happy. Furthermore, bars and shops where no big purchases are expected don't have such a device nor a lot change. Anyway, banks usually give change to non customers.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: They have to judge the risk. Stranger making €5 purchase with €100 note - you risk losing €100, and that's what someone with forged money would do, so the risk is huge. Stranger making €100 purchase with €100 note - you risk losing the cost of the €100 purchase. Riskier if it is something that is hard to resell. But of course the customer could come back and ask for a refund; receiving €100 genuine money for €100 fake. €100 note from known customer - little risk.

Comment: Re "Spanish Here": you probably meant to say "Spaniard here". Just to improve your English a bit - it is not my first language either :-)

Answer (score 19):

In almost every major and minor store, supermarket and bar, there are signs / drawings / notices that state : "The cashier won't accept cash payments of over €100/200/500" depending on the size of the store.

The reason? to prevent dealing with false notes, to prevent money laundering, and to prevent having to deal with lot of cash (and its inherent responsibility) in case of robbery (doesn't happen as commonly as in USA, but is a legit fear to have).

PS: there's also a law that completely bans any type of cash transaction of over €2,000.

PS-2: the next law applies to every store, business, bar, supermarket, etc. :

**59.1.e) del Real Decreto 2816/1982** - every public oriented company is free to pick which clients it wants to serve, as long as the requirements to meet are not racist / of hate.

This article clearly states that a store, bar, or whatever, can refuse to serve you as client as long as there is no invalid reason (race, religion, skin colour).

This includes clothing (refusing you because you're shirt-less is valid), weird or non-permitted payment methods, being an awful whining client…

Sources: I live in Spain.

Comment: "doesn't happen as commonly as in USA" = not true... Spain has 201 robberies per 100k population while US had 146 ([source](http://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/stats/Crime/Robberies)).

Comment: that data is not only 10 year old and biased, but doesn't even state sources . on the other hand, data from past year states that over 39% of spain's "robberies" are employee shopliftings. on the other hand, in 2015, usa had an economical impact of 1.6% of the total sales, belgium 1.5%, and france and spain had 1,4 %. the robbery ( non-employee theft) per capita  was at  7.7 robberies per 10.000 inhabitants on 2014.

Comment: sources, spain wins slightly to usa in the 2015 charts on this one : http://phx.corporate-ir.net/External.File?item=UGFyZW50SUQ9NjAwMzY3fENoaWxkSUQ9MzExNTk3fFR5cGU9MQ==&t=1

Comment: and let's not start on the more important point : armed robberies per capita.

Answer (score 11):

In many countries in the eurozone, shops tend to post signs along the lines of “we refuse banknotes larger than €100” for various reasons so in that sense, €500 would indeed not be well accepted. They are however still perfectly valid, even as the ECB announced it would stop issuing new ones.

In general private banks should therefore have no problem with it but might not necessarily offer cash services to non-customers. If nothing else works, you should however be [able to exchange them at one of the branches of the Banco de España](http://www.new-euro-banknotes.eu/News-Events/PRESS-RELEASES-PRESS-KITS/ECB-ENDS-PRODUCTION-AND-ISSUANCE-OF-%E2%82%AC500-BANKNOTE).

No matter what you do, if you want to change a large amount of cash, you might have to present ID or satisfy some other reporting requirement.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they are accepted, of course. 500 euros notes are perfectly legal. As stated before, you might have trouble using then in some places.

In the other hand, there are places that will accept them regardless of the amount you buy. One of this kind of places is one of the biggest commercial galleries chain in Spain, called "[El Corte Ingles](https://www.elcorteingles.es/)". Those stores are almost everywhere (in all big cities, and most smaller ones), and will accept your bank note without hesitation, even for small amounts bought. You can go there, buy a 12€ music cd, for example, and get your change in smaller notes.

Answer (score 11):

**Banks:** It has been mentioned that banks will accept to change 500€ notes. Don't count on this! I have been present (I live in Spain) when people try to do just this and get refused. There seems to be some discretion here, but its impossible to fathom. The main argument used is that it is the bank's policy not to change money for non-clients and that it has to go through an account, i.e. you pay your large note into your account and take money back out of the account in whatever form is convenient for you. The idea being to generate a paper trail for possible fraud or money laundering investigations.

Answer (score 5):

As others have posted, the €200 and €500 bills are not accepted in small stores, for amounts easily payable with lower denominations.

I worked ten years ago at a fast food restaurant and we were responsible for any cash imbalance -- meaning a counterfeited €500 bill could ruin your monthly pay... one or two months!

Having said that, and despite the fame of Spain regarding the number of €500 bills here, for normal people these bills are extremely rare to see, so having to handle one of these is awkward. The same applies, and these are even rarer, for €200 notes.

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Banks will accept them, most retailers won't.  You will be able to exchange those 500€ bills for smaller ones at the bank, still you will need to carry all that money with you.  Why not just put the money on a savings account and use a credit/debit card.  I don't know where you live, maybe you will loose a small exchange fee but walking around with a lot of money means you can loose all of it.  My boss had his wallet stolen last year in Barcelona.  I'm not saying crime in Spain is higher than somewhere else, just advising not to take any risks when it's not necessary and you will not gain a lot by taking the risk.

Comment: This does not really answer the question beyond what has been said in the other answers.

Comment: @mts I thought the fact of pointing out the risk was worth the post. I was thinking about posting as a comment first but decided to go for an answer because of all the comments the post had already.

Comment: Crime is not high in Spain, but pickpocketing to tourist is a major concern in Barcelona. Therefore, I would avoid carrying a lot of cash while looking as a tourist in a touristic zone.

Comment: I actually like this answer for suggesting the use of a debit/credit card, because it's the best idea and it seems to me nobody suggested it (me included)

Answer (score -7):

The EU may have a Legal Tender rule similar to the US (I do not know).  If so, then *technically*, they cannot be refused.

However, there are practical considerations that make such large denominations difficult to use.

The most common reason is the merchant's simple inability to provide change.  In the US, many merchants try to keep  less than $100 in the register.

It was explained to me by a banker friend that a business can refuse a large bill by simply refusing the transaction.  This is legal because they are not specifically refusing the note and "having only $100 notes" is not a protected class.

A retail bank should accept the note without issue.

Note, I am fully aware that a merchant is not compelled to accept any current for any reason.  *There is no misconception here.*

Comment: This is a commonly misunderstood. Legal tender means that the note must be accepted in satisfaction of a debt. In a store transaction, as your banker friend notes, there's generally no debt; the store can refuse the transaction, so the concept of legal tender does not apply. I expect that any such laws in the eurozone vary from one country to the next.

Comment: I know, that's why I explicitly described how the merchant can refuse a note by refusing the transaction, *not the note itself*.  In cases where a dept has already been incurred, it's slightly different but courts have ruled that a merchant's inability to make change in no way affects the purchasers requirement to settle.

Comment: Downvote totally unwarrented.  In no way did I suggest a merchant is compelled to accept any currency.

Comment: for what it's worth, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Didn't think so.  It happened after you're comment.  Most likely, someone misunderstood your point, which is otherwise correct.

Comment: @phoog The fact that “legal tender” doesn't apply in a US store is no reason to believe that Spain doesn't have such a rule. For example in France, a store *is* required to accept any valid coin or banknote as long as the customer gives exact change (on the other hand, the merchant would be allowed to refuse a €500 bill if the customer had to pay €499.99). I don't know if Spain has a similar rule; indeed these vary even inside the Eurozone.

Comment: Let's not split hairs here.  If the Hot Dog vendor doesn't want the high value note, they just refuse to sell you the Hot Dog.  If you try to pay a $1250 hotel bill with 12 $100 bills and some change, the hotelier will have difficulty refusing the currency.

Comment: Keep in mind also that even when the money is being used for the payment of a debt (such as in a restaurant), there is no responsibility on the part of the payee to give change (at least in the UK).

Comment: @Gilles Your example explicitly excludes the most common case in which the store is being asked to provide change.  But does this mean that it is impossible to open a store in France that accepts card payments only?

Comment: @phoog I don't know. [This government site](http://www.economie.gouv.fr/dgccrf/Moyen-de-paiement) claims that “cash payments may not be refused” but it doesn't state under which conditions this applies (for example I'm pretty sure that no-cash parking meters are legal).

Comment: I downvoted because "technically, they cannot be refused" is *flat out wrong* as an answer to the OP's question.  If you attempt to pay for a pack of chewing gum with a 500 euro note, it can and will be refused.

Comment: That's why I explained explicitly how a business can refuse any currency and why they're unlikely to accept a 500 Euro note or $100 bill.  So, like, whatever.

Comment: @Johns-305 Your answer may be more clear, and therefore attract fewer downvotes if you put your main point first in the answer ["they can refuse the high value notes"]. The technical point about the basis for their refusal (they can't refuse the currency under US law but they can refuse the transaction??) can come later, for the more enthusiastic legal scholars. ;)

Comment: Downvoted, because the question is specifically about Spain and the info provided is for the USA.

Comment: Tanks for the feedback, but since other Answers indicate the rules are the same, my answer does not change.

Comment: So in summary, the answer to the question about whether 500 Euro notes are accepted in Spain, is that $100 bills can't be refused in the US except when they are.

Comment: Um, no.  Is anybody actually reading the Answer?  Are 500 Euro notes accepted in Spain, yes, they are valid Euro currency.  Can the Merchant refuse them, yes.  Why is this so hard to understand?

Comment: And if that's all your answer is saying, what does it add to the other answers?